# toggle arrow image change

Tags: jquery, css

I want to change the toggle arrow image based on the particular toggle panel

http://jsfiddle.net/47MRH/1/

based on the click i want to toggle between the right and down arrows

CSS:-

```
.icon
{
height:14px;
width:14px;
float:left;
position:relative;
margin-right:10px;
background:url("http://glyphicons.com/wp-   content/themes/glyphicons/images/glyphicons_halflings.png") no-repeat;
}

.icon-rightarrow
{
background-position:-456px -72px;
}

.icon-downarrow
{
background-position:-313px -119px;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Add this line: http://jsfiddle.net/47MRH/2/

```
j(this).closest('li').find('.icon')
                     .toggleClass('icon-rightarrow, icon-downarrow');
```

use `.toggleClass()` to `toggle between the classes` to `right` and `down` arrow icon.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with the [AddClass](http://api.jquery.com/addClass/) and [RemoveClass](http://api.jquery.com/removeClass/) functions.

The following will change a right-arrow to a down-arrow:

```
$("#MyElementId").removeClass("icon-rightarrow");
$("#MyElementId").addClass("icon-downarrow");
```

[Here is your updated example](http://jsfiddle.net/47MRH/5/)